# IMU frame transfer to body frame

Tags: transform, robotic-arm, imu, gyroscope, accelerometer

I am just wondering how do we transfer IMU readings to Body frame? Especially, linear speed and acceleration.

In following diagram, the IMU is mounted on one of the surfaces of the body (you can imaging it to be a bot, vehicle, drone, or etc.). The center of the vehicle is at Body (green) point in this diagram, and it is on a different surface of the body. Both IMU and Body point are on a rigid body which moving in an inertial frame.

Any hint is highly appreciated. I'd really appreciate if there are some references. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you may take use of rotation/ homogenous transformation matrices. It can help you convert a vector define wrt one co-ordinate frame to another. And the fact that both frames don't have any relative motion wrt each other makes the task easier. To construct these matrices, you need to know the relative position and orientation of the frames (like how far is their origin in xyz direction, what is their relative orientation/ rotation). Once you construct them, it will be just a simple matrix pre-multiplication operation with the readings you got to get the readings in different frame.

It might seem daunting if this is something new to you but it actually isn't. All the best!

Have a look at this : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html and https://mecharithm.com/learning/lesson/homogenous-transformation-matrices-configurations-in-robotics-12